# Grounding paths of a capacitor discharge circuit

Tags: grounding

I would like to know how to properly ground the following circuit with 12V input and 390V output.

Do I attach all the ground symbols to negative side of my 12V dc supply near input and all high voltage ground symbols to  ground on output side of dc boost converter?

I was wondering would the feed capacitor close to input (220uF, 25v) blow since it’s positive side is connecting to anode on SCR and cathode would connect to the capacitor.

[image]!

Comment: I love chips with no pin numbers...

Comment: Cropping this image would help. Plus adding pin numbers.

Comment: Completely redrawing it would be better. Add pin numbers, number the components and give them all values, and put positive at the top, GND at the bottom. And the answer is yes.

Comment: It’s not my circuit... I have a better image but was told the image file size was too large. The SCR’s used are displayed in the image. From left to right it’s cathode, anode, gate. Thank you Brian for an actual answer. If I needed a list of ways to improve the circuit I would have asked.